# How to add in a specific index of com.google.gson.JsonArray?

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

`com.google.gson.JsonArray` has add method which will append the element. If I would like to add at specific index, how to do that?

I tried with this kind of code to add element at 0th index. I am looking for something better without instantiating a new `JsonArray`.

```
JsonArray newArray = new JsonArray();
newArray.add(new JsonPrimitive(3));
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); i++) {
    newArray.add(myArray.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Could you post an example of the json you'd wish to create?  An array always starts at 0.  Maybe you mean a map?

Comment: (e.g. Initial JSON array is like this [1,2,3] now I would like to add 0 at 0th index , after addition it will be [0,1,2,3] )

Answer (score 7):

Since there is no insert method for JsonArray, it means you have to make your own.  It inserts a single item in the array at the point of your choosing.

```
public static JsonArray insert(int index, JsonElement val, JsonArray currentArray) {
    JsonArray newArray = new JsonArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        newArray.add(currentArray.get(i));
    }
    newArray.add(val);

    for (int i = index; i < currentArray.size(); i++) {
        newArray.add(currentArray.get(i));
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

So using this method, to insert a new item 0 into an existing array [1, 2, 3] at position 0:

```
insert(0, new JsonPrimitive(0), myArray);
```

Without altering the original array, the method will return a new array [0, 1, 2, 3]. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is the only way, You nicely put it into a method, which we can reuse. Every time we have to create a new JsonArray. Instead void return type should be a JsonArray (May be it is a typo).

Comment: @DebmalyaJash Oops, you're right.  I made the corrections.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @Neil, another thing instead of JsonPrimitive val, if i use JsonElement val , then i can add complex type of things also.

Comment: JsonArray oldArray = new JsonArray(); JsonObject arrayElement = new JsonObject();
  arrayElement.add("Comment", new JsonPrimitive ("Playing with JsonArray")); JsonArray newArray = JSONUtil.insert(0, new JsonPrimitive(0), oldArray);  newArray = JSONUtil.insert(1, arrayElement, newArray);

Comment: @DebmalyaJash Yes, of course you can pass any object you wish in the place of JsonPrimitive, so long as it can be added to JsonArray.  Made the corrections.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt response.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this, you can replace an existing JsonElement at a particular index using the method mentioned below.

JsonElement set(int index, JsonElement element)
Replaces the element at the specified position in this array with the specified element.

For reference:

https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonArray.html#set-int-com.google.gson.JsonElement-

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not want to replace any existing element , I want to add an element at a specific index (e.g. Initial JSON array is like this [1,2,3] now I would like to add 0 at 0th index , after addition it will be [0,1,2,3]

Comment: I am unable to see any builtin functionality that supports it, you will have to manually merge two JsonArray as you already have.